# System.FormatException: 'String '"2022-04-14 13:03:12"' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Tags: c#, database, datetime

```
cnn.Open();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:/Users/jhogan/Documents/Test Folder/test_import.csv"))
                {
                  while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                  {
                      var line = reader.ReadLine();
                      if (lineNumber != 0)
                      {
                         var values = line.Split(',');
                         var date = values[0];
                         var sentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    
                         await cnn.ExecuteAsync(insertFeedback, new { 
       @SentDate = sentDate, @RatedDate = values[1], @Rating = values[2], @Location = values[3], @Notes = values[4], @Email = values[5], @Feedback = values[6] },commandTimeout: 120,commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);}
```

I am attempting to load this data from a csv file into my database, but am running into the following error from the title. The original formatting of the date from my csv is HH:MM:SS PM/AM and my column type in the database is datetime. In my database, the datetime formatting is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:MMM. I think this is because of the database's formatting of things, but I am genuinely not sure.

Comment: You should use the format from the csv in `ParseExact`. You could try `var sentDate = new DateTime(values[0]);` That will use the current date but it seems there is no date in the csv - just the time?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1179 ... Note that you really should use proper Date type for database columns instead of strings...

Comment: this is very odd - your text says the CSV has format "HH:MM:SS PM/AM" but the error message says something else. Can you please include a part of the CSV

Comment: @pm100 the first row is 4/14/2022  1:03:12 PM. Typo, you can see the date format is M/DD/YYYY H:MM:SS PM

Comment: *"In my database, the datetime formatting"* in databases, dates don't have formats, they are binary types. You can store them in `varchar` columns, but why would you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my column type in the database is datetime. In my database, the datetime formatting is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:MMM.

You misunderstand how the database and .Net DateTime values work. If the column type or data type is `DateTime`, the format in the database or in memory is **binary**, and when you see `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:MMM` that's just a *convenience* provided for you by your tooling. There is no need to ever try to match your string to that internal binary format.

But as for the code, the problem is the lower-case `hh` in the format string. We can see in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) the lower-case `h` is for 12-hour times and upper-case `H` is for 24 hour times. Looking at the input string `2022-04-14 13:03:12` from the error in the question title, we have a `13` in this position, which definitely puts you in upper-case `H` territory:

```
var sentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

But it's worse than that. I also see this in a comment:

> the first row is 4/14/2022 1:03:12 PM

So first of all, the format string for `DateTime.ParseExact()` tells the format of the original input source string, *not the target format for the parsed value*, which is, after all, binary and not human readable anyway.

The format string to parse that value would look like this: `M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt`. Also note the use of paired vs single characters in certain positions.

```
var sentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But the real significance here is the variation between the error in the question title and the comment means you might have a *mix of formats.* That's scary. `DateTime.ParseExact()` uses **strict** parsing. If the input does not **EXACTLY** match the expected format you *WILL* get an exception.

Fortunately, there is an [overload for the method that accepts multiple format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-parseexact(system-string-system-string()-system-iformatprovider-system-globalization-datetimestyles)). Even with this overload, though, you probably need to take the time to review the csv data and make sure that *every possible format in the data* is accounted for.

And if data for this field could be entered by random humans may God have mercy on your soul.

Comment: Thank you for your response - this explains things very well.  After reviewing the file,  all dates are the same format of M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt. I used your suggested code: 
```
var sentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```
But I still received the same error message.

Comment: @JosephHogan The error message includes the exact string, which does not at all match the value you saw in the csv file, so something else is messing with your data. You should find out what.

Comment: it looks like the original file contained quotations around the values originally, so I had to parse them out. Thank you for your assistance.